# Issues with running two instances of searchd

Tags: sphinx, ubuntu-10.04

I have just updated our Sphinx server from 1.10-beta to 2.0.6-release, and now I have run into some issues with `searchd`. Previously we were able to run two instances of `searchd` next to each other by specifying two different config-files, i.e:

```
searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf
searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.staging.conf
```

sphinx.conf listens to `9306:mysql41`, and `9312`, while sphinx.staging.conf listens to `9307:mysql41` and `9313`.

After we updated to 2.0.6 however, a second instance is never started. Or rather.. the output makes it seem like it starts, and a pid-file is created etc. But for some reason only the first searchd instance keeps running, and the second seems to shutdown right away. So while trying to run `searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf` twice (if that was the first one started) complains that the pid-file is in use, trying to run `searchd --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.staging.conf` (if that is the second started instance) "starts" the daemon again and again, only no new process is created..
Note that if I switch these commands around when first creating the process, then `sphinx.conf` is the instance not really started.

I have checked, and rechecked, that these ports are only used by `searchd`.

Does anyone have any idea of what I can do/try next? I've installed it from source on ubuntu 10.04 LTS with:

```
./configure --prefix /etc/sphinx --with-mysql --enable-id64 --with-libstemmer
make -j4 install
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note to self: **Check the logs!**

RT-indices use binary logs to enable crash recovery. Since my old config files did not specify a path for where these should be stored, both instances of `searchd` tried to write to the same binary logs. The instance started last was of course not permitted to manipulate these files, and thus exited with a fatal error:

```
[Fri Nov  2 17:13:32.262 2012] [ 5346] FATAL: failed to lock
    '/etc/sphinx/var/data/binlog.lock': 11 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
[Fri Nov  2 17:13:32.264 2012] [ 5345] Child process 5346 has been finished, 
    exit code 1. Watchdog finishes also. Good bye!
```

The solution was simple, ensure to specify a `binlog_path` inside the `searchd` configuration section of each configuration file:

```
searchd
{
[...]
   binlog_path = /path/to/writable/directory
[...]
}
```

Comment: I am not using RT index only local indexes but not able to run the searchd with different sphinx.conf file located on desktop it is pointing to only default sphinx.conf file. [here is my question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832046/sphinx-search-deamon-not-working-on-different-port)